# How to find out what these syscall_983045, syscall_322 syscalls in strace output?

Tags: android, linux, system-calls, strace

I saw these two syscall in my strace log a lot.

What's the best way to found out what those syscall mean?

I tried include/linux/syscalls.h in the linux kernel source tree.  But can't find anything there.

This android ics system.   Linux 3.0 code.

```
[pid   144] syscall_322(0xa, 0x1ba3b, 0x24000, 0, 0x3, 0x2, 0xa, 0x142, 0x1b6d8, 0xa, 0x181a0, 0x181a0, 0, 0xbecfda98, 0x400dbbe5, 0x400cf4d4, 0x60000010, 0xa, 0xb691, 0, 0x7379732f, 0x2f6d6574, 0x2f62696c, 0x6462696c, 0x732e6d76, 0x6f73006f, 0x746e6569, 0x6f732e, 0x6f, 0x6f732e, 0x442000, 0x30303200 <unfinished ...>


[pid   169] syscall_983045(0xb001b878, 0xb001d0c4, 0xffffffc8, 0, 0, 0xb00094f0, 0xbefcac30, 0xf0005, 0xb001b878, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xbefcabe0, 0xb00047c3, 0xb0001200, 0x10, 0xb001b878, 0xb691, 0, 0x6363612f, 0x69752f74, 0x30312f64, 0x742f3030, 0x736b7361, 0x3a746900, 0x746e6569, 0x6f732e, 0x6f, 0x6f732e, 0x442000, 0x30303200) = 0
[pid   170] close(9)                    = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it, in case other need to know:

```
$ grep 983045 ./development/ndk/platforms/android-3/include/sys/linux-syscalls.h
#define __NR_ARM_set_tls                  (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE + 983045)
$ grep 322 ./development/ndk/platforms/android-3/include/sys/linux-syscalls.h
#define __NR_openat                       (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE + 322)
```